# Subset of a table that contains at least one element of another table

Tags: r, subset

I have two tables that are made by intervals of bp, the Table1 has large intervals and the second has short intervals (just 2bp). I want to make a new table that contains only the Table 1 ranges that have at least one element of table 2 contained in their "large" ranges. If doesn´t have an element in the table 2 that corresponds to the table 1 range, this range of Table 1 should be not included.

In this example row 2 (`1, 600, 1500`) of Table1 (`df`) should be not included:

```
df <- "Chromosome start end
    1  1 450
    1 600 1500 
    2 3500 3585 
    2 7850 10000"
df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)
```

Table2 (`df2`)

```
df2 <- "Chromosome start end
    1 5 6
    1 598 599 
    2 3580 3581 
    2 7851 7852
    2  7859 7860"

df2 <- read.table(text=df2, header=T)
```

NewTable (`dfout`):

```
dfout <- "Chromosome start end
1 1 450
2 3500 3585
2 7850 10000"

dfout <- read.table(text=df2, header=T)
```

Comment: What is your specific question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You may need to clarify what the logic is for how an item is included or not included. It would also help to say what "bp" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `foverlaps` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df1), Chromosome, start, end)
setkey(setDT(df2), Chromosome, start, end)
setnames(unique(foverlaps(df1, df2, nomatch=0)[, c(1,4:5),
                         with=FALSE]), names(df1))[]
#   Chromosome start   end
#1:          1     1   450
#2:          2  3500  3585
#3:          2  7850 10000
```

Or as @Arun commented, we can use `which=TRUE` (to extract the indices) and subset 'df1' using `yid` column.

```
df1[unique(foverlaps(df2, df1, nomatch=0L, which=TRUE)$yid)]
#    Chromosome start   end
#1:          1     1   450
#2:          2  3500  3585
#3:          2  7850 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to solve your problem:

```
ranges <- merge(df,df2,by="Chromosome",suffixes=c("A","B"))
ranges <- ranges[with(ranges, startA <= startB & endA >= endB),]
ranges <- ranges[,1:3]
dfout <- unique(ranges)
    dfout
# Chromosome startA  endA
#     1      1   450
#     2   3500  3585
#     2   7850 10000
```